# Automorphism of the group of rational numbers under addition

Tags: galois-theory

Let $\mathbb \phi $ be an automorphism of the group of rational numbers $\mathbb \ Q$ under addition.  Prove that $\mathbb \phi(x)=x \phi(1), \forall x \in Q. $

Comment: yes, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answer is almost correct. We do have
$$
\phi(n) = \phi(1+1+\cdots +1) = \phi(1) + \cdots +\phi(1) = n\phi(1)\\
\phi(1) = \phi\left(\frac nn\right) = \phi\left(\frac1n+\frac1n+\cdots+\frac1n\right) = \phi\left(\frac1n\right)+\cdots + \phi\left(\frac1n\right) = n\phi\left(\frac1n\right)
$$
where the last line gives $\phi\left(\frac1n\right) = \frac1n\phi(1)$. However, for a general fraction $\frac mn$, we need to do the following:
$$
\phi\left(\frac mn\right) = \phi\left(\frac 1n + \cdots +\frac1n\right) = \phi\left(\frac 1n\right) +\cdots + \phi\left(\frac 1n\right) = m\phi\left(\frac1n\right) = m\frac1n\phi\left(1\right)
$$
which is what we want.

Answer (score 0):

$\phi$ is homomorphism, therefore we have $$\phi(n) = \phi(1+1+\cdots + 1) = \phi(1) + \phi(1) + \cdots + \phi(1) = n\phi(1)$$

in the same way $$n \phi\left(\frac1n\right) = \phi(1) \to \phi\left(\frac1n\right) = \frac 1n \phi(1)$$  using the above two, we can conclude $$\phi\left(\frac mn\right) = \phi(m\frac{1}{n}) =\phi(m)\phi\left(\frac1n\right) =\frac m n \phi(1)\phi(1) = \frac m n \phi(1)$$

Comment: This is very close to a true answer, but the transition $\phi\left(m\frac1n\right) = \phi(m)\phi\left(\frac1n\right)$ requires that we're talking about rings, and we're not. This is a _group_ question. That's also why you get $\phi(1)\phi(1) = \phi(1)$ at the end, which is not true in general.

Answer (score -1):

Every automorphism $Φ$ of the rational numbers $\Bbb Q$ under addition to itself has the form $Φ(x)=xΦ(1)$.

Proof:

Let $Φ:(Q,+)→(Q,+)$ be an automorphism.

Let $x∈Q ⇒ x=m/n \text{ where } m,n\in\Bbb Z \text{ and }n\ne0$

$Φ(m)$

$=Φ(1+1+\dots +1)$

$=Φ(1)+Φ(1)+\dots +Φ(1)\ m$-times (Since $Φ$ is an automorphism)

$=mΦ(1).$

$Φ(1)$

$=Φ(n/n)$

$=Φ(1/n + 1/n + \dots + 1/n)$

$=Φ(1/n)+Φ(1/n)+ \dots$

Comment: Your answer adds nothing new to the existing answers.